# jquery.royalslider.min.js https issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin for jquery Royal Slide and it seems i cannot get the video to work. When i checked console i see:

It seems the issue is:

> http://www.youtube.com/embed/Cid9kQuwJyc?rel=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&wmode=transparent'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

the module automatically changes it to http even though i entered a https youtube url in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue was with jquery.royalslider.min.js file itself that automates the hyperlink with http.

To resolve go to:

```
/wp-content/themes/templatename/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js?ver=4.8
```

on line 89 change

```
<iframe src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/ id ?rel=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&wmode=transparent” frameborder=”no”></iframe>’
```

to:

```
<iframe src=”https://www.youtube.com/embed/ id ?rel=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&wmode=transparent” frameborder=”no”></iframe>’
```

so that it includes

> https

rather than http. You can do this with all other sources too (i.e vimeo etc)

Comment: to remove suggestions:

line 89

'https://www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?rel=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&wmode=transparent'

Change rel=1 to rel=0